# 64 bit ROM on arm-v7

Tags: custom-roms, lineageos

I'm not finding a stable Lineage armeabi-v7 ROM for my Moto G6.

All I found was a 64 bit Lineage ROM meant for another codename (my phone's codename is "Ali". The 64 bits phone seems to be "Evert")

Also found an unofficial 64bit TWRP for the Ali (doesn't say which XT).

If I flash this recovery, is there a way to predict if I'm gonna be able to flash a x64 ROM ? Or trial and error ?

I lose a whole day to customize the phone after a flashing goes wrong (happenned twice this week), even using titanium, and android's native backup. That's why I ask if someone has experience on this particular case before jumping.

If the architecture isn't problem enough (processor seems to support x64), there's the Vendor and other partitions that usually aren't bundled onto custom ROMs...

```
XT-1925-5

Qualcomm Snapdragon 450

8xARM Cortex-A53

GPU Adreno 506
```

This question could also become cannonical/General.

Comment: what's wrong with 64 bit? https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/twrp-unofficial-twrp-64-bit-3-6-1.4328145

Comment: So, I CAN put a 64bit ROM on a armv7 phone ? Please note it's a XT1925-5 model. If yes, I'll try it immediately. But if I understood correctly, only the models above that are 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

IT DOES WORK
The 64 Bit TWRP and ROM DO work on an arm-v7

- First I installed the Unofficial TWRP (mali.img)
- Then  [this unofficial ROM](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/rom-unofficial-11-moto-g6-ali-lineageos-18-1-by-fwiep.4469945/)
- Gapps must be Pico, or else no space on /system.

Reminding that my device is a XT1925-5

**DO NOT** install TWRP app as a system app. If you did, there is an uninstall option on the TWRP advanced