# Google Wallet gets replaced by Google Pay

Tags: lineageos, google-wallet

Weirdest shenanigan:

I just installed Lineage 18 and gapps, then Google Wallet (from the store).
But the wallet does not get installed: the defunct **Google Pay** takes its place !

Problem is: this Google Pay detects the root. Wallet used to work (after all the root hiding modules)

And now it got worse, the app is giving that error message: *Google pay is currently updating so you won't be able to access the app*
Can't even attempt to use it

Wiping data, dalvik, etc doesn't change anything

The ROM and device is [from this question here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/246462/64-bit-rom-on-arm-v7)
Also asked the ROM developers to see if they have a clue

**Feb 4:**
Tried making the app system (using the Systemizer module), but no difference.

Also noticed that just right after installing the app, **both** the Wallet and the Pay coexist on the app drawer.
For a moment, though: if I choose wallet, it disappears and runs the Pay

Answer (score 0):

Found out this is NORMAL
Somehow...

Apparently, on THIS VERY ROM, the google Pay takes precedence over the Wallet.
I have an Official 18.1 Lineage on an S7, and the Wallet app takes precedence there.

All works:

- Shamiko, USNF 2.3.1MOD2.1, MagiskHidePropsConfig (spoofing myself), HiddenCore Module;
- Play Store, Play Services, and Wallet on the Deny list. Don't force DenyList;
- Wipe data of the three above. Uninstall the updates of them all, disable them, reboot, and do the reverse. Let them update themselves from the store.

At first, GPay will be unavailable, as it really IS updating itself (internally?).